# Have tag badges not yet been enabled?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

The tab badge page says that to receive a bronze badge:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

[Madara Uchiha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/27/madara-uchiha) should have received the [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto) bronze badge. Are tag badges not yet enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another criterion, there has to be at least 100 overall questions in the tag in question. There're currently only 75.

Once we have 100 [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto) questions, all badges should be awarded.

For more information, visit the **[official FAQ page on tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63835/166899)**.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.